# flash cs5 transparent png issue on android screens

Tags: android, flash, png, transparency, photoshop

I am creating images in Photoshop with a **transparent** background. I am calling them into flash dynamically with actionscript 3 but the transparency has a white ghostly look to them. I can see the boxes move around on my **ANDROID** devices.

I found this tutorial and it helps: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/128/tn_12804.html#main_Known_issues_with_transparent_bitmaps

HOWEVER I want to import the images dynamically and not have to bring each image in to flash and fix it. Any ideas on what settings will work when exporting from photoshop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a "WORK AROUND" solution.

I created a **transparent PNG** TO COVER THE ENTIRE SCREEN. I loaded it in the second level
above the background image. There may be a ever so faint "ghosting" look but I can't tell by looking. One thing for sure it removed the boxes around the other transparent PNG files I am loading in. So that's great!

Please let me know if this helped you. Thanks

-Ed Vizenor